# How to remove an element from a group of elements?

Tags: jsoup

Given the code below:

**HTML:**

```html
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

**JS:**

```js
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(baseHtml);
Elements elements = doc.select("div");
elements.get(1).remove();
// remove doesn't affect elements. why?
elements.size();   // equal 3
// but this works
doc.outerHtml() // <div>a</div><div>c</div>
```

Do I have to use this code to get removed elements? It seems too verbose.

```js
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(baseHtml);
Elements elements = doc.select("div");
elements.get(1).remove();
elements = doc.select("div");
```

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If yes please accept one, so this topic can be considered closed. If not, please let the community know so we can provide further help.

Answer (score 5):

This should help you:

```
public class TestJsoup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.ro").get();
            Elements select = doc.select("div");
            System.out.println(select.size());
            select.remove(1);
            System.out.println(select.size());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestJsoup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked why this doesn't work

```
elements.get(1).remove();
// remove doesn't affect elements. why?
```

The answer can be found in the implementation.
The method you call on the element is a method implemented in 
the `Node` class.

```
public void remove() {
    Validate.notNull(this.parentNode);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

As you see calling `remove()` removed this element from the parent 
(if you print the document, you will see that the element `b` has been
removed. But that doesn't mean that has been deleted from the list of 
elements that the class `Elements` holds.

```
public class Elements implements List<Element>, Cloneable {
    private List<Element> contents;
```

In order to do that you have to do it the way @Silviu Burcea showed you, 
by calling the method `remove(int index)` you are calling the below method
which can be found implemented in the `Elements` class

```
public Element remove(int index) {
    return ((Element) this.contents.remove(index));
}
```

Although bare in mind, that if you do that, the only thing that you do, is to
remove the i-th element from the list that `Elements` class contains.

Check these examples

**Example 1:** The size of elements is reduced, but the document remains the same

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String baseHtml =   "<div>a</div>" +
                            "<div>b</div>" +
                            "<div>c</div>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(baseHtml);
        Elements elements = doc.select("div");
        elements.remove(1);
        System.out.println(doc.outerHtml());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println(elements.size());   
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println(doc.outerHtml()); 
    }
}
```

**Example 2:** The elements remains the same, but the document changes

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String baseHtml =   "<div>a</div>" +
                            "<div>b</div>" +
                            "<div>c</div>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(baseHtml);
        Elements elements = doc.select("div");
        elements.get(1).remove();
        System.out.println(doc.outerHtml());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println(elements.size());   
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println(doc.outerHtml()); 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps to clear the confusion.