# How to remove one letter in Jsoup?

Tags: java, string, parsing, double, jsoup

I am having troubles with parsing string into double. I am trying to get the price of an item but the string returns in a value like: $24.54. So the problem (I'm assumming) is that it is conflicting with the $. Is there a way to eleminate the $ and turn the 24.54 into a double and store in a variable. Here is the code: (PS I am a C++ programmer haven't programmed in Java for a while so feel free to give me tips):

```
Elements tdsInSecondRow = doc.select("table tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)"); //Test the changing of these numbers
        Elements prices = doc.select("table tr:eq(1) > td:eq(2)");
        for (Element td : tdsInSecondRow)
        {
            String word = td.text(); //Saved the text into symbol
            double price = Double.parseDouble(prices.text());
            System.out.println(symbol);
            System.out.println(price);
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061693/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-group-of-elements

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `double` to hold a currency value. Consider `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if your text starts with "$".

```
if(word.startsWith("$")){
 word = word.substring(1, word.length());
}

double price = Double.parseDouble(word.text());
```

Hope it helps,