# Jsoup keep only clean <p> tags and delete everything else

Tags: java, html, jsoup

This seems like a simple solution but I can't for the life of me work it out.

I have a collection of elements which are made up from a mix of `<p>` and <`p class="example">` along with a few `<p><strong>...</strong></p>`.

All I want to do is keep everything (including the tags and it's string) which is a clean `<p>` tag.

What I'm using at the moment does most of what I want, but I really can't seem to get rid of `<p><strong>...</strong></p>`

```
@Override
public String fetchContent(String url) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Element body = document.select("article.story_landing").first();
    Elements elements = body.select("p:not([class])").select("p:not([id])");

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (Node child : elements) {
        if (child.attributes().size() <= 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(child.toString());
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Basically I want to delete the entire `<p></p>` tag if it contains anything other than text in both it's attributes and it's body.

Any easy way to do this?

Cheers

**Edit #1**
A HTML example of what I have, and what I want back. Sorry for the confusion!

```
<div class="item-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p><strong>LOREM IPSUM:<br> *&nbsp;
        <a href="https://example.com"
           title="">Some random link</a><br> *&nbsp;
        <a href="https://example.com"
           title="">Some random link</a><br> *&nbsp;
        <a href="https://example.com"
           title="">Some random link</a><br> *&nbsp;
        <a href="https://example.com"
           title="">Some random link</a><br> *&nbsp;
    </strong>
    </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p><a class="some_class" href="http://example.com">Some rando link</a></p>

    <p><a class="some_class" href="http://example.com">Some rando link</a></p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>
</div>
```

And I just want the clean `<p>` tags and their content, the rest of the elements can be deleted.

```
<div class="item-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac eleifend risus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please, post your html code you need to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't how I was parsing the HTML, the issue was my lack of understanding on how `jsoup` handles `remove` when called from an `Element` object. It doesn't remove it from the collection as I'd expect, it does however remove it from the `Document`.

As you can see from my code in the question, I was using the result of the removal operation to build a string, which of course would contain the elements I didn't want, even though they had been removed from the `Document`.

The final working solution (be it still messy) looks like

```
public String fetchContent(String url) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Element body = document.select("article.story_landing").first();
    Elements elements = body.getElementsByTag("p");

    for (int i = 0; i <= elements.size(); i++) {
        if (elements.get(i).children().size() != 0) {
            elements.remove(i);
        }
    }

    for (Node child : elements) {
        if (child.attributes().size() <= 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(child.toString());
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The information I found very helpful was [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061693/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-group-of-elements) where the removal operation is explained.

Still love to hear a better solution to my problem if anyone has one!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `<p>` tags that have elements inside of them, you could simply check if they have any children with the following code:

```
Elements allPTags = doc.getElementsByTag("p");

for(Element p : allPTags){
    // If size() isn't 0 it means that the p tag has children elements so 
    // remove it from the from the document.
    if(p.children().size() != 0){ 
        p.remove();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I understand what your requirements are for removing the tags with attributes, but this should take care of removing the ones with elements inside them.