# unable to save the modified HTML file using JSoup and Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium-webdriver

I need to modify the existing HTML file and save the same. Though I am able to modify but unable to save the changes back to HTML file.

[image]

The modification that i am trying to do is i am trying to delete one table `<table class='runtime-table table-striped table'>` out of two  which is present below html code and want the changes to be saved

Below is the snippet of the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /> 
    <meta name='description' content='' />
    <meta name='robots' content='noodp, noydir' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
    <meta id="timeStampFormat" name="timeStampFormat" content='MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a'/>
    
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/extent-framework/extent-github-cdn@ff53917fbbdb5ef820abbbe4d199a6942dc771ff/v3html/css/extent.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    <title>HALS Brands</title>

    <style type='text/css'>
        /* json-tree */
        .jstBracket,.jstComma,.jstValue{white-space:pre-wrap}.jstValue{font-size:10px;font-weight:400;font-family:"Lucida Console",Monaco,monospace}.jstProperty{color:#666;word-wrap:break-word}.jstBool{color:#2525CC}.jstNum{color:#D036D0}.jstNull{color:gray}.jstStr{color:#2DB669}.jstFold:after{content:' -';cursor:pointer}.jstExpand{white-space:normal}.jstExpand:after{content:' +';cursor:pointer}.jstFolded{white-space:normal!important}.jstHiddenBlock{display:none}
            
      
        
        img.r-img {width:60%;}     
        
      
    
    </style>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*! json-tree - v0.2.2 - 2017-09-25, MIT LICENSE */
        var JSONTree=function(){var n={"&":"&amp;","<":"&lt;",">":"&gt;",'"':"&quot;","'":"&#x27;","/":"&#x2F;"},t=0,r=0;this.create=function(n,t){return r+=1,N(u(n,0,!1),{class:"jstValue"})};var e=function(t){return t.replace(/[&<>'"]/g,function(t){return n[t]})},s=function(){return r+"_"+t++},u=function(n,t,r){if(null===n)return f(r?t:0);switch(typeof n){case"boolean":return l(n,r?t:0);case"number":return i(n,r?t:0);case"string":return o(n,r?t:0);default:return n instanceof Array?a(n,t,r):c(n,t,r)}},c=function(n,t,r){var e=s(),u=Object.keys(n).map(function(r){return j(r,n[r],t+1,!0)}).join(m()),c=[g("{",r?t:0,e),N(u,{id:e}),p("}",t)].join("\n");return N(c,{})},a=function(n,t,r){var e=s(),c=n.map(function(n){return u(n,t+1,!0)}).join(m());return[g("[",r?t:0,e),N(c,{id:e}),p("]",t)].join("\n")},o=function(n,t){var r=e(JSON.stringify(n));return N(v(r,t),{class:"jstStr"})},i=function(n,t){return N(v(n,t),{class:"jstNum"})},l=function(n,t){return N(v(n,t),{class:"jstBool"})},f=function(n){return N(v("null",n),{class:"jstNull"})},j=function(n,t,r){var s=v(e(JSON.stringify(n))+": ",r),c=N(u(t,r,!1),{});return N(s+c,{class:"jstProperty"})},m=function(){return N(",\n",{class:"jstComma"})},N=function(n,t){return d("span",t,n)},d=function(n,t,r){return"<"+n+Object.keys(t).map(function(n){return" "+n+'="'+t[n]+'"'}).join("")+">"+r+"</"+n+">"},g=function(n,t,r){return N(v(n,t),{class:"jstBracket"})+N("",{class:"jstFold",onclick:"JSONTree.toggle('"+r+"')"})};this.toggle=function(n){var t=document.getElementById(n),r=t.parentNode,e=t.previousElementSibling;""===t.className?(t.className="jstHiddenBlock",r.className="jstFolded",e.className="jstExpand"):(t.className="",r.className="",e.className="jstFold")};var p=function(n,t){return N(v(n,t),{})},v=function(n,t){return Array(2*t+1).join(" ")+n};return this}();
    </script>
</head>
    <body class='extent standard default hide-overflow bdd-report'>
        <div id='theme-selector' alt='Click to toggle theme. To enable by default, use theme configuration.' title='Click to toggle theme. To enable by default, use theme configuration.'>
            <span><i class='material-icons'>desktop_windows</i></span>
        </div>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo black"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/extent-framework/extent-github-cdn/d74480e/commons/img/logo.png"></a>
        <!-- slideout menu -->
        <ul id='slide-out' class='side-nav fixed hide-on-med-and-down'>
            <li class='waves-effect active'><a href='#!' view='test-view' onclick="configureView(0);chartsView('test');"><i class='material-icons'>dashboard</i></a></li>
                        <li class='waves-effect'><a href='#!' view='category-view' onclick="configureView(1)"><i class='material-icons'>label_outline</i></a></li>
            <li class='waves-effect'><a href='#!' view='exception-view' onclick="configureView(2)"><i class='material-icons'>bug_report</i></a></li>
            <li class='waves-effect'><a href='#!' onclick="configureView(-1);chartsView('dashboard');" view='dashboard-view'><i class='material-icons'>track_changes</i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- report name -->
        <span class='report-name'>HALS Brands - Automation Report</span>
        <!-- report headline -->
        <span class='report-headline'></span>
        <!-- nav-right -->
        <ul id='nav-mobile' class='right hide-on-med-and-down nav-right'>
            <a href='#!'>
            <span class='label blue darken-3 suite-start-time'>Feb 2, 2021 01:32:39 AM</span>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>      <!-- container -->
        <div class='container'>
<div id='test-view' class='view'>
    <section id='controls'>
        <div class='controls grey lighten-4'>
            <!-- test toggle -->
            <div class='chip transparent'>
                <a class='dropdown-button tests-toggle' data-activates='tests-toggle' data-constrainwidth='true' data-beloworigin='true' data-hover='true' href='#'>
                <i class='material-icons'>warning</i> Status
                </a>
                <ul id='tests-toggle' class='dropdown-content'>
                                        <li status='pass'><a href='#!'>Pass <i class='material-icons green-text'>check_circle</i></a></li>
                    <li status='fail'><a href='#!'>Fail <i class='material-icons red-text'>cancel</i></a></li>
                    <li status='skip'><a href='#!'>Skip <i class='material-icons cyan-text'>redo</i></a></li>
                    <li class='divider'></li>
                    <li status='clear' clear='true'><a href='#!'>Clear Filters <i class='material-icons'>clear</i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- test toggle -->
            <!-- category toggle -->
            <div class='chip transparent'>
                <a class='dropdown-button category-toggle' data-activates='category-toggle' data-constrainwidth='false' data-beloworigin='true' data-hover='true' href='#'>
                <i class='material-icons'>local_offer</i> Category
                </a>
                <ul id='category-toggle' class='dropdown-content'>
                    <li><a href='#'>@sanity_api1bal</a></li>
                    <li class='divider'></li>
                    <li class='clear'><a href='#!' clear='true'>Clear Filters</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- category toggle -->
            <!-- clear filters -->
            <div class='chip transparent hide'>
                <a class='' id='clear-filters' alt='Clear Filters' title='Clear Filters'>
                <i class='material-icons'>close</i> Clear
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- clear filters -->
            <!-- enable dashboard -->
            <div id='toggle-test-view-charts' class='chip transparent'>
                <a class='pink-text' id='enable-dashboard' alt='Enable Dashboard' title='Enable Dashboard'>
                <i class='material-icons'>track_changes</i> Dashboard
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- enable dashboard -->
            <!-- search -->
            <div class='chip transparent' alt='Search Tests' title='Search Tests'>
                <a href="#" class='search-div'>
                <i class='material-icons'>search</i> Search
                </a>
                <div class='input-field left hide'>
                    <input id='search-tests' type='text' class='validate browser-default' placeholder='Search Tests...'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- search -->
        </div>
    </section>
<div id='test-view-charts' class='subview-full'>
    <div id='charts-row' class='row nm-v nm-h'>
        <div class='col s12 m4 l4 np-h'>
            <div class='card-panel nm-v'>
                <div class='left panel-name'>Features</div>
                <div class='chart-box' style="max-height:94px;">
                    <canvas id='parent-analysis' width='90' height='70'></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class='block text-small'>
                    <span class='tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='0%'><span class='strong'>0</span> feature(s) passed</span>
                </div>
                <div class='block text-small'>
                    <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='100%'>1</span> feature(s) failed, <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='0%'>0</span> skipped
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col s12 m4 l4 np-h'>
            <div class='card-panel nm-v'>
                <div class='left panel-name'>Scenarios</div>
                <div class='chart-box' style="max-height:94px;">
                    <canvas id='child-analysis' width='90' height='70'></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class='block text-small'>
                    <span class='tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='0%'><span class='strong'>0</span> scenario(s) passed</span>
                </div>
                <div class='block text-small'>
                    <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='100%'>2</span> scenario(s) failed, 
                    <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='0%'>0</span> skipped, 
                    <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='0%'>0</span> others
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col s12 m4 l4 np-h'>
            <div class='card-panel nm-v'>
                <div class='left panel-name'>Steps</div>
                <div class='chart-box' style="max-height:94px;">
                    <canvas id='grandchild-analysis' width='90' height='70'></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class='block text-small'>
                    <span class='tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='57.143%'><span class='strong'>8</span> step(s) passed</span>
                </div>
                <div class='block text-small'>
                    <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='14.286%'>2</span> scenario(s) failed, 
                    <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='28.571%'>4</span> skipped, 
                    <span class='strong tooltipped' data-position='top' data-tooltip='28.571%'>0</span> others
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="timeline-chart" class="row nm-v nm-h">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12 np-h">
            <div class="card-panel">
                <div class='left panel-name'>Timeline (seconds)</div>
                <div class="chart-box" style="width:98%;max-height:145px;">
                    <canvas id="timeline" height="120"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <div class='subview-left left'>
        <div class='view-summary'>
            <ul id='test-collection' class='test-collection'>
                <li class='test displayed active has-leaf fail' status='fail' bdd='true' test-id='1'>
                    <div class='test-heading'>
                        <span class='test-name'>E2E_Services_Sanity_TC_01_ProductAPI_PRODUCT_All Products_Active_Tier_Price</span>
                        <span class='test-time'>Feb 2, 2021 01:32:41 AM</span>
                        <span class='test-status right fail'>fail</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='test-content hide'>
<div class="sr-filters bdd-filters">
    <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light pass green" title="pass"><i class='material-icons'>check_circle</i></a>
    <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light fail red" title="fail"><i class='material-icons'>cancel</i></a>
    <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light skip blue" title="skip"><i class='material-icons'>redo</i></a>
    <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light clear grey" title="clear"><i class='material-icons'>clear</i></a>
</div>
<div class='scenario outline node' test-id='2' status='fail'>
    <span class='duration right label'>0h 0m 12s+489ms</span>
    <div class="bdd-test">
        <div class="scenario-name"><span class='status fail' title='fail'><i class='material-icons'>cancel</i></span> Scenario Outline: Verify Product API is retrieving activeTierAndPrices for particular location</div>
  <table class='runtime-table table-striped table'><tr><td>brand</td><td>locationId</td><td>sellingChannel</td><td>productId</td><td>responseCode</td><td>responseFileName</td><td>productId_DB</td></tr><tr><td>HALS</td><td>8023</td><td>WEBOA</td><td>HALS-WEBOA-640213214</td><td>200</td><td>E2E_Services_Sanity_TC01_Response.json</td><td>HALS-STORE-640213214</td></tr><tr><td>HALS</td><td>1700</td><td>WEBOA</td><td>HALS-WEBOA-640213214</td><td>200</td><td>E2E_Services_Sanity_TC01_Response.json</td><td>HALS-STORE-640213214</td></tr></table>
<table class='runtime-table table-striped table'><tr><td>brand</td><td>locationId</td><td>sellingChannel</td><td>productId</td><td>responseCode</td><td>responseFileName</td><td>productId_DB</td></tr><tr><td>HALS</td><td>8023</td><td>WEBOA</td><td>HALS-WEBOA-640213214</td><td>200</td><td>E2E_Services_Sanity_TC01_Response.json</td><td>HALS-STORE-640213214</td></tr><tr><td>HALS</td><td>1700</td><td>WEBOA</td><td>HALS-WEBOA-640213214</td><td>200</td><td>E2E_Services_Sanity_TC01_Response.json</td><td>HALS-STORE-640213214</td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <ul class='steps'>
        <li test-id='3' class='node scenario fail' status='fail'>
            <div class="step-name" title=""><span class='status fail' title='fail'><i class='material-icons'>cancel</i></span>Verify Product API is retrieving activeTierAndPrices for particular location</div>
            <ul class='gc steps'>
```

My Java code to traverse through Html. I was successful in removing the second table but it failed to save the changes back to file

```
    File htmlFile = new File("C:\\Automation_Report\\Extent_HTML_Reports\\ExtentHtml.html");
    
    //PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(htmlFile,"UTF-8");
    
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlFile, "UTF-8");
    
    Elements element1 = document.getElementsByClass("runtime-table table-striped table");
    
    System.err.println(" Size : "+element1.size());
    System.out.println("");
    
    System.out.println("Before Deleting");
    System.out.println("===========================================");
    System.out.println(element1);

    if(element1.size()>1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=element1.size();i++)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {
                //element1.get(i).empty();
                element1.remove(1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Before Deleting");
    System.out.println("===========================================");
    System.out.println(element1);
            
    Path output = Path.of("C:\\Automation_Report\\Extent_HTML_Reports\\filename1.html");
    Files.writeString(output, document.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

element1.remove(1); will remove element from elements

element1.get(1).remove(); will remove element from document.

please set location of file according to yours.

```
public class JSOUPExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    File htmlFile = new File("D:\\ExtentHtml.html");
    try {       
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlFile, "UTF-8");
        
        Elements element1 = document.getElementsByClass("runtime-table table-striped table");
        
        System.err.println(" Size : "+element1.size());
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("Before Deleting");
        System.out.println("===========================================");
        System.out.println(element1);
        
        
        
        /*if(element1.size()>1)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=element1.size();i++)
            {
                if(i==1)
                {
                    //element1.get(i).empty();
                    element1.remove(1);
                }
            }
        }*/
        element1.get(1).remove();
        
        System.out.println("After Deleting");
        System.out.println("===========================================");
        System.out.println(element1);
                
        Path output = Path.of("D:\\filename1.html");
        Files.writeString(output, document.html()  );
        

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

For more info please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27159035/10830316)

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I see its just the same piece of my logic that you saying I tried it but failed to save the changes to file.

Comment: no I commented your code. and replaced with  element1.get(1).remove();. there is difference between element1.remove(1); and  element1.get(1).remove();.. Now in my above code changes are saved in html file and it is working please check it.